# -webkit-transform height is changing viewport on mobile safari

Tags: css, webkit, fancybox, mobile-safari, transform

Note: please read my comment first.

I'm building an iPad specific web app. I'm using fancybox to overlay a window with content in when a link is clicked - though I don't think my problem is specific to fancybox.

I'm trying to bring up the overlay, then animating it to fullscreen (changing position and dimensions). I'm trying to write a fancybox transition using css3 transform, rather than the traditional animated ones that come out of the box, in order to get acceleration. I'm almost there, but I'm running into an odd problem...

When I apply the transform to change the height of the overlay, the viewport changes - it zooms out. No matter what size I resize the box to in terms of height, the viewport zooms out (the bigger I make the box, the more the viewport zooms out). I am using the meta tag: . The odd thing is that this doesn't happen width. The width of the overlay transforms nicely to full screen width, no viewport changes.  It's just with the height.

Any ideas? I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

Here's some code in case it helps. Note: I've made some changes to the fancybook lib, so if you see something that looks odd below, that's why. As I said, I don't think this is anything to do with Fancybox, it's mobile Safari that I'm struggling with.

The transition:

```
var F = $.fancybox;

F.transitions.fullScreen = function() {
var cssProps = F._getPosition(true);
cssProps.top = parseInt(cssProps.top, 10) + 'px';
cssProps.opacity = 1;

// set the wrapper to its starting point and show it
F.wrap.css(cssProps).show(); 
$(".fancybox-inner").css({width:cssProps.width, height:cssProps.height});

window.setTimeout(function(){
    var leftPos = F.wrap.offset().left;
    var topPos = F.wrap.offset().top;
    $(".fancybox-wrap").css({"-webkit-transform": "translate3d(-"+leftPos+"px,-"+topPos+"px,0)", width: "880px", height: "500px" });

},200)

};
```

The CSS:

```
.fancybox-wrap{
-webkit-transition:all 1s ease-in;  
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
-webkit-transition-duration: 1000ms;  
}
```

Cheers

Comment: I've extracted most of the code, away from my app into a test app, and the viewport zooming doesn't doesn't happen. It works as expected. So I think all the code I've added up there ^^ is OK. It's just something with how I'm using fancybox. If anyone has seen anything like this before, and can shed some light, be great to know. As it is, I'm going to have to refactor fancybox out, which is a shame.